# maximum property of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T>0$, $w:\mathbb R^n\times (0,T]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and $w$ has a strict lokal maximum in $(x_0,T)$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R$. Define $$\tilde w(x,t):= w(x,t) - \frac{\varepsilon}{T-t}$$ for $x\in\mathbb R^n, 0<t<T$.

For $\varepsilon >0$ small enough, $\tilde w$ has a local maximum in some point $(x_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)$ with $0<t_\varepsilon<T$ and we can choose this point such that $(x_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)\to (x_0,t_0)$ for $\varepsilon\to 0$.

I am trying to formally prove this, but I already get stuck calculating the maximum.

What I want to do is calculate the maximum and then show that $(x_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)\to (x_0,t_0)$. Since $x_\varepsilon=x_0$ we already have $x_\varepsilon \to x_0$, but I am a little stuck with the $t_\varepsilon$-part:

So we obviously have $\frac{\partial\tilde w}{\partial x} = w_x(x,t)$ for which we already know that this is zero at $x_\varepsilon=x_0$.

But how about $$\frac{\partial \tilde w}{\partial t} = w_t(x,t) - \frac{\varepsilon}{(T-t)^2}=0$$

I have no idea how to solve this for $t$ to get my $t_\varepsilon$. Does anyone have an idea on how to go on with this? Thanks!

Comment: The first thought that occurs to me is that you should not use or reason about derivatives at all, especially since the differentiability of $f$ is not assumed. Instead, focus on the local properties of $w$ near $(x_0,T)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can assume without loss of generality that $(x_0,T)$ is a *global* maximum of $w$. To see this, note that $w(x,t)<w(x_0,T)$ in some compact neighbourhood $K$ of $(x_0,T)$ (except at that point itself), so there is some $m<w(x_0,T)$ so that $w<m$ on the boundary of $K$ (except the part where $t=T$). Now replace $w$ by $w\wedge m$ outside $K$, turning the local maximum into a global one.

Now for each $\delta>0$, put $K_\delta=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,T]\colon w(x,t)\ge w(x_0,T)-\delta\}$, and convince yourself that for small enough $\delta$, $K_\delta$ is compact, and this set shrinks to the single point $(x_0,T)$ as $\delta\to0$.

You should find that when $\delta>0$ is fixed and $\varepsilon$ is small enough, $\tilde w$ has a global maximum $(x_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)$ which happens to lie in $K_\delta$.

And that should pretty much finish the proof. I'll leave the mopping up of the details to you.